# How to speed up loading data at start of shiny app

Tags: r, database, docker, shiny

I'm pretty new to using shiny apps to visualize data. We plan to host our shiny app on our own server. So for that we used docker to deploy our app. However the app is super slow to load, since we have to load a lot of (big) dataframes (up to 10000000 rows x 10 columns), that are saved within a RData object.
My first question is: Will the data be loaded each time a user visits/reloads the website?
I was looking into ways how to spead up loading the data. One possbility might be to use the `feather` package, which seems to be faster in loading data tables.

Another option would be to put the data into a database. However I do not have experience with that. I saw there are some nice packages like `DBI` and `RMariaDB` that seem to work well with shiny app. However, I only find examples where an exterinal database is queried. Is it possible to pack a MySQL database within the docker and access it from within the shiny app? Or is the normal procedure to host the database externally?

I'm really new to all this, so I'm not even sure if I'm asking the right questions. These are the conditions: We have a lot of data in the form of multiple data tables. Those need to be read into our app quickly and needs to be queried quickly through interactive user input. We need to dockerize our app in order to deploy it. What is the best approach here?

Comment: Stack Overflow works best for specific programming questions. This seems to be made up of too many parts with possible opinion based answers. If you want a site that does more general discussions, try https://community.rstudio.com/ instead. You need to clearly define what "best" means -- what tradeoffs are you willing to make/

Comment: I agree with @Mr.Flick that this question is probably off topic. In the mean time, I have two thoughts for you. 1) Read the data faster, with a package like `feather`. [See here for more info](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/).  2) Preload the data in Global.R, but beware [scoping problems](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html).

Comment: Thank you for the comments and pointers! I also asked the question on the Rstudio community: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-speed-up-loading-data-at-start-of-shiny-app/59923